# How to capturing global keyboard and mouse events in a desktop application in KMP

Tags: kotlin

How do I capturing global keyboard and mouse events in a desktop application in Kotlin Multi Platform native compilation?

It is for Linux, Windows and MacOS.

I tried in Kotlin using Java libraries but it’s just too heavy and slow to start.